# Test for symmetry for polar graphs

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

From a calculus book I'm reading: "Unlike the graphs of an equation in $x$ and $y$, the graph of an equation $r=f(\theta)$ can be symmetric with respect to the polar axis, the line $\theta = \pi/2$, or the pole *without* satisfying one of the tests for symmetry. This is true because of the many different ways of specifying a point in polar coordinates."

Why is the previous paragraph true? Why are there many ways to specify a point in polar coordinates and how does that affect the symmetry test?

Comment: The origin has infinitely many "names" $(0,\theta)$ where $\theta$ can be anything. And every point $(r,\theta)$ could also be called $(r,\theta+2n\pi)$, $n$ any integer. How that affects symmetry tests is unclear: it should not affect a properly constructed symmetry test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The origin has infinitely many "names" $(0,\theta)$ where $\theta$ can be anything. And every point $(r,\theta)$ could also be called $(r,\theta+2n\pi)$, $n$ any integer. How that affects symmetry tests is unclear: it should not affect a properly constructed symmetry test. –  André Nicolas on [July 27, 2013, at 7:06](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453293/test-for-symmetry-for-polar-graphs#comment974778_453293)

André has posted what I think is a satisfactory answer in the comments, hence this wiki answer.